# Проблема с виртуальными хостами

Tags: apache2.4

Создал виртуальные хосты на ip `127.0.0.1`, для каждого порта свой хост. При переходе по ip `127.0.0.1:8082` отображает `Hello VHost2!`, при переходе по ip `127.0.0.1:8083` отображает `Hello VHost1!`. Но не переходит по именам `test1.ru` и `test2.ru`.

В настройках `httpd-vhost`:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8083

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8082


<VirtualHost *:8083>

    DocumentRoot "C:\webprog\Apache24\htdocs\webprog\virthost1\www"
    ServerName  test1.ru
    ErrorLog "C:\webprog\Apache24\htdocs\webprog\vhlogs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\webprog\Apache24\htdocs\webprog\vhlogs\access.log" common

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8082>

    DocumentRoot "C:\webprog\Apache24\htdocs\webprog\virthost2\www"
    ServerName  test2.ru
    ErrorLog "C:\webprog\Apache24\htdocs\webprog\vhlogs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\webprog\Apache24\htdocs\webprog\vhlogs\access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

В настройках `hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost

127.0.0.1  test1.ru

127.0.0.1  test2.ru
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Что означает фраза «не переходит по именам test1.ru и test2.ru»? Вы настроили прослушивание портов 8083 и 8082 — вы не забываете указывать эти порты после соответствующих имён?

Comment: При написании в браузере test1.ru:8083 и test2.ru:8082 отображает соответствующие страницы. А есть ли возможность, чтобы настроить отображение страницы в браузере при указании просто имени test1.ru и test2.ru?

Comment: Без указания порта используется порт по умолчанию — 80 для http или 443 для https